# Python metaclasses: using arguments of class.__init__ to modify class in metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I am currently trying to wrap my head around metaclasses for a particular problem:
 - a container class needs to expose some functions from its elements
 - the container class cannot be modified afterwards

Metaclasses seem to be a good way to accomplish the above (e.g. `__slots__` can be modified in `__new__`.

Example:

```
import inspect

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        ...
        # modify slots ?
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        name = args[0]
        elements = args[1]

        tmp_class = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        ds_methods = [m for m, _ in inspect.getmembers(tmp_class, predicate=inspect.ismethod)]
        e_methods = [m for m, _ in inspect.getmembers(elements[0], predicate=inspect.ismethod) if m not in ds_methods]

        attrs = {m:f for m, f in inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.ismethod)}
        # for testing map to print
        new_attr = {m: print for m in e_methods}
        attrs.update(new_attr)
        .... # call __new__?
        # this does not contain the new methods
        newclass =  cls.__new__(cls, cls.__name__, [object], attrs)


class Container(metaclass=MyMeta):
    __slots__ = ['_name', '_elements']
    def __init__(self, name, elements):
         self._name = name
         self._elements = elements
```

In short: the only way I found to modify slots is in `__new__` and the only way to intercept creation arguments is in `__call__`.

There is probably a much simpler way to accomplish this (the above does not work), I would be thankful for any pointers to help me better understand metaclasses.

Comment: The question is missing "what are you trying to achieve" - it has your code, it has an anbiguous phrase - but since the code is wrong, and there is not an example of how you'd like that to work, it is very hard to understand what you actually want.

Comment: For example: what are the parameters "name" and "elements". Why "elements[0]" ? Do you want to strip elements of the class available on each instance? Do you want to generate a new class each time an instance is created with new parameters??

Comment: _what_ modifications you want to do to  `__slots__`? Or  at least, why do you think you'd need that?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I want to
 a) intercept elements from the class
 b) check the type of the element, .eg. `elments[0]` and extract public methods (`len(elements)` is always `> 1`)
 c) map public element methods to Container methods, e.g. `Container.print()` would execute `print` for each element
 d) freeze the class with `__slots__`